# Icons in rich text box?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

A simple question :) how do I insert icons into a richtextbox.

For example I want " :-) " to be replaced by, say, ImageList[1] ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think only way is using Paste option.

Try this code

```
    private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains(":-)"))
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Find(":-)", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 3;

        Clipboard.SetImage(im.Images["smile.png"]);
        this.richTextBox1.Paste();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad idea: it modifies the clipboard without the user's knowledge.

Comment: Yes I agree, can replace with this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490734/programatically-adding-images-to-rtf-document