# How to open word file with images and bullets in a rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop

Hi i am open a word file 2007(.doc file) in a rich text box through open dialog box.
It works fine but images and bullets are not shown in a rich text box.
i want to open open word file with images and bullets in a rich text box.

I am using this code for open a word file and convert it to sentence by sentence.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
object File = txtfilepath.Text; //this is the path
object nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordobject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordobject.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document docs = wordObject.Documents.Open(ref File, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
                ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
                ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
                ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
                docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
                docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
                IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                rtbgermanfile.Text = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
                string name = rtbgermanfile.Text.Trim();
                name = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, name.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
                string newtext = name.Replace("\n\n", "\n");
                string newtext2 = newtext.Replace("\n\n", "\n");
                rtbgermanfile.Text = newtext2.ToString();
                txtwriteingerman.Text = rtbgermanfile.Lines[0];
                docs.Close(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
                wordobject.Quit(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
                //wordobject.Quit(SaveChanges:false, OriginalFormat: false, RouteDocument: false);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordobject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is all that easy.  RTF or ANSI are the text data format's for rich text box if I recall correctly (maybe any of the TextDataFormat types). I can't talk to ANSI but RTF is not a great tool.

suggest using word itself. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office2010developertrainingcourse_gettingstartedlab_topic3.aspx

But if RTF check out this one for a hint of how to do this. [Programmatically adding Images to RTF Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490734/programatically-adding-images-to-rtf-document)