# Check for empty text from a rich text editor

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsf

How to check for empty text from a rich text editor?

I have a Rich text, similar to this one where I am typing.

By default, the value is set to `<br>` so, in Java when i check for `request.getParameter("desc");` I will get the value as `<br>`

I want to check for empty string, including any html tags like just `<br><hr>` etc

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. what have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried `descStr = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(descStr);` but this converts to `&lt;br&gt;` for a `<br>`. I am expecting an empty space or line, and I can do `descStr.length==0` to check if its empty, so this didnt work for me. is there an easy way to fix, if not I will have to change the solution.

Comment: @Andrew, would you recommend storing the rich text editor's content in a hidden Field, as anyone types, and pass it to backend could do the trick. I never tried, but just came up in mind, or will it be the same anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

```
String text = Jsoup.parse(html).text();

if (text.isEmpty()) {
    // No text.
}
```

Additional advantage is that it can also help you with [sanitizing](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) HTML to avoid XSS attacks when a malicious enduser enters e.g. a `<script>` in your text area. You were also checking on that, right?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. That was a precise solution, and its nice to know about that library. Cleaning HTML was the other issue I had and thought of posting next, and you saved my night. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simple-minded, but just remove all tag *words* (includes image and button).

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String text) {
    return text.replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "").trim().isEmpty();
}
```

Maybe with a replaceAll removal of whitespace and line breaks.

Assumes that a non-tag `<` is given as entity `&lt;`.

Comment: That was interesting. I combined the Jsoup suggested by BalusC to check embedded html content and your suggestion to clean up the tags in text, and did the trick. Thanks for this. But I think Jsoup seems to have these built in already using WhiteList or so, and looks to have clean way to clean the html tags, so I will proceed with that solution. Thanks for your response too.

Comment: is there a solution for not skipping images?

Comment: @Vi_Hari the html tags for images `<img ...>` could be kept with a regex negative lookahead on "img" but that does not make it as normal image, or RTF image or such. Either again a conversion to HTML with prepending `"<html>"` or converting them to RTF (if that is your intended format); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490734/programmatically-adding-images-to-rtf-document