# how do I add an image in a richTextBox?

Tags: c#, image, richtextbox

hello how can I add an image in a richTextBox? I would like to put my signature at the bottom of a richTextBox document which is updated with variables

```
{  Image firmadir = Image.FromFile(@"C:\\Users\\Utente\\Pictures\\firma.jpg");
        Clipboard.SetImage(firmadir);
        richTextBox1.Copy();


        richTextBox1.Text = "da:" + spazio + "                                a:" + acapo + "Nome e Cognome: Gatti" + spazio + "Nome e Cognome:" + nome_e_CognomeTextBox.Text
            + acapo + "indirizzo: Via Stampa 40" + spazio + "Ragione sociale:" + nome_SocietaTextBox.Text
            + acapo + "Città:Modena                 " + spazio + "indirizzo:" + indirizzoTextBox.Text
            + acapo + "provincia:Mo                 " + spazio + "citta:" + cittaTextBox.Text + "                                    "
            + acapo + spazio + "                                      provincia:" + provinciaTextBox.Text
            + acapo + spazio + "                                      cap" + capTextBox.Text
        + acapo + acapo + acapo + "desiderata:" + desiderataTextBox.Text
        + acapo + acapo + "struttura del sito"
        + acapo + acapo
        + paginerich.Text
        + richTextBox2.Text + acapo
        + "Modalità di pagamento" + acapo + "il pagamento può avvenire  tramite bonifico o in liquidi, sarà effettuato in tre parti, alla prima verifica, con conseguente conferma del mandato, saranno versati euro " + primaverificaTextBox.Text + " quando il cliente sarà soddisfatto e non vi saranno più modifiche da fare nella struttura, il cliente verserà euro " + finestrutturaTextBox.Text + " Al termine dell'inserimento dei contenuti sarà versato la cifra finale Euro"
+ finecontenutoTextBox.Text
+ acapo + acapo + "data" + DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("d")
+ acapo
+ acapo
+firmadir}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490734/programmatically-adding-images-to-rtf-document) may help.  But you should also probably visit the help center to learn [what to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: if I do  Clipboard.SetImage(img)
            RichTextBox1.Paste() display text not image  with text after

Comment: Please read the _what to ask_ link in my comment above.  Specifically, _[this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)_.   At a minimum your post should include a [mcve] showing what you have tried, and where it goes wrong.  Also, from the functions you referred to in your comment it appears you are using `C#`, not `C`. (as you have tagged this question.)  They are different languages.

Comment: Code needs to be edited into your post.  It is unreadable in the comment.

Comment: Oh - Your so funny!

Comment: how do to wride code?

Comment: [How can I insert an image into a RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542850/how-can-i-insert-an-image-into-a-richtextbox/568378)