# *.rtf files are larger than the *.docx files

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a word editor project (VB.NET) which saves the file in `.rtf` file format. The one problem I am facing now if I insert an image and save the file, the file size increases more than I thought.

As an example, if I insert 45 KB size of the image and save the file in `.rtf` format, it has taken 5 MB of space where `.docx` takes only 55 KB of space.

So, my question is there any way to reduce the file size in the `.rtf` file format.

Comment: RTF?  No, because it's a text format.

Comment: Is the 45KB image the size of the file as a JPEG? Was the image embedded in the Word file or was it a link to the image? (You can open a docx file as if it were a zip file (because that is what it is) in a utility such as 7-zip to see what is inside it.) Maybe [Programmatically adding Images to RTF Document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1490734/1115360) will lead you to something useful.