# Remove the ability to resize an image pasted into a richtextbox and add an event to that image. C#

Tags: c#, image, events, resize, richtextbox

I have searhed high and low for a solution to this problem.  I have no problem adding an Bitmap image into the richtextbox.  The problem is that I don't want it to have the resize option to it.  I want that one image to be SELECTED when I click on it, just like in most messengers, and to throw an onclick event.  Any help in this area would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found the following solution: Insert images/objects using IRichEditOle. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/MyExtRichTextBox.aspx explains how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a question about inserting an image manually building the RTF code. I suspect for any sort of custom functionality you will have to build the RTF for it as well.
[How can I insert an image into a RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542850/how-can-i-insert-an-image-into-a-richtextbox)

Here is the RTF Spec documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140277%28office.10%29.aspx