# How to get image from RichEditBox

Tags: c#, image, uwp, richeditbox

I have a RichEditBox in which I have already inserted an image through code. Now, I want to get the inserted image after some process.
Is there any way to get image from RichEditBox?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: how you inserted it?  than you should the same way get it back

Comment: Hi prasanth, did u found any solution for this, even i am also in same situation to get back images from richeditbox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting images from RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376897/extracting-images-from-richtextbox)

Answer (score 1):

I found two old question here that may help you.

1. [Extracting images from RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376897/extracting-images-from-richtextbox)
2. [Extract Embedded Image Object in RTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779647/extract-embedded-image-object-in-rtf)

Comment: i am creating uwp app. And have RichEditBox not RichTextBox. I also tried all methods described into the above links but with no success.