# UWP RichEditBox disable image resize

Tags: uwp, richeditbox

I'm trying to build a native editor in which i have a rich edit box in which i insert an image. I'm able to resize the image from the editor, how can I disable resizing. Al[image]so how can i get the inserted image back.

Comment: Do you insert image with [`InsertImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextrange.insertimage) api?

Comment: Yes Document.Selection.InsertImage

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Also the rich edit box doesnot have horizontal scrolling for tables that are wider than the screen width.

Comment: Disable image resize mean the keep original size insert to RichEditBox ? am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm able to resize the image from the editor, how can I disable resizing

If you want to keep image original size and insert to `RichEditBox`, you could get the image `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` value with `BitmapImage` like the follow.

```
Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker open = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
open.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))

    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        await image.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
        Test.Document.Selection.InsertImage(image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, VerticalCharacterAlignment.Baseline, "img", fileStream);
    }
}
```

> Also how can i get the inserted image

Derive from this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48260489/7254781), you could parse picture data from your selected rtf text. Then use regular expression to filter available data. The follow is a complete code that you could use directly.

```
private async void GetImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string rtf = "";
    Test.Document.Selection.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out rtf);
    string imageDataHex = "";
    var r = new Regex(@"pict[\s\S]+?[\r\n](?<imagedata>[\s\S]+)[\r\n]\}\\par", RegexOptions.None);
    var m = r.Match(rtf);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        imageDataHex = m.Groups["imagedata"].Value;
    }
    byte[] imageBuffer = ToBinary(imageDataHex);
    StorageFile tempfile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("temppic.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(tempfile, imageBuffer.AsBuffer());
}

public static byte[] ToBinary(string imageDataHex)
{
    //this function taken entirely from:
    // http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter
    if (imageDataHex == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("imageDataHex");
    }

    int hexDigits = imageDataHex.Length;
    int dataSize = hexDigits / 2;
    byte[] imageDataBinary = new byte[dataSize];

    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2);

    int dataPos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hexDigits; i++)
    {
        char c = imageDataHex[i];
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            continue;
        }
        hex.Append(imageDataHex[i]);
        if (hex.Length == 2)
        {
            imageDataBinary[dataPos] = byte.Parse(hex.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            dataPos++;
            hex.Remove(0, 2);
        }
    }
    return imageDataBinary;
}
```

Comment: Resizing the image i mean by the attached image. I have edited the question please check into the attachement.

Comment: I have tried insert picture, but it could show the resize point flag in my side. could you told how did you do that?

Comment: After adding the image pls double click on that u can see the resize points

Comment: double click the image was selected but resize points did not show ?

Comment: OMG. why its behaving weird for me. Its the screen shot i attached.    Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png");
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile imageFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(imageUri);
            using (Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream ras = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {

                Editor.Document.Selection.InsertImage(15, 15, 0, Windows.UI.Text.VerticalCharacterAlignment.Baseline, "Local_Image_ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png", ras);
            }

Comment: <RichEditBox Name="Editor" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ContentLinkBackgroundColor="Red" ContentLinkForegroundColor="Yellow" IsHandwritingViewEnabled="True"> 
        </RichEditBox>

Comment: Also i couldnot perform a horizontal scroll on richeditbox.  Also please sugggest me idea to add blockquote in a richeditbox.

Comment: for horizontal  scroll, you need give RichEditBox Fixed width, and make the value of  `TextWrapping` false.

Comment: I have the inverted problem. I want to make it possible to resize images in a `RichEditBox`, but according to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086403/how-to-display-resizing-adorner-in-an-ima), it seems that this is not possible. How is "disable resizing" meant in this question?