# UWP RichEditBox ITextRange has image

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, richeditbox

I have a richeditbox in which i need to find out if an ITextRange has an image or not. Please help me with this.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide a minimal example, containing what you tried so far: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Actually i found that by finding if the character value is 65532 (standard value for objects) But now i'm unable to add a block quote to the RichEditBox.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar It seems you have found a solution to find out if there is an Image in the RichEditBox in your new thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610093/uwp-richeditbox-disable-image-resize). Please let me know whether you need more help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP RichEditBox disable image resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610093/uwp-richeditbox-disable-image-resize)