# Is it possible to insert a picturebox in between the textbox's lines?

Tags: c#, textbox, picturebox

i am making a messenger application something like windows live messenger.
when a user want to send some data or attachments to the other end user, he can upload a picture for example, in my application the other end receives the picture by a new form popping out on the screen saying "you have received an attachment/picture" open/close ... etc.
my question is, is it possible to insert the picture box the the textbox that shows chat texts?
it is like putting it on a new line between the other texts, that are showing in the logs.

Comment: I would rather create a separate custom control, but yeah, you could achieve your intended goal using simple WinForm controls. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542850/how-can-i-insert-an-image-into-a-richtextbox) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add images to `TextBox` control, You have to use `RichTextBox` but still problem persists. You have to use `Clipboard` in order to Add Image to `RichTextBox`.

```
Clipboard.SetImage(image);
richTextBox.SelectionStart = index;//where you want image
richTextBox.Paste();
```

Above code will help you to add Image to `RichTextBox` but then there's no easy way to manipulate over it.

Alternatively you can take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R), this looks promising and I've used it a bit ago.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **RichTextBox** for this purpose. That will serve your purpose really well. Textbox is a simple control used for text only and doesn't has such features.