# Replacing ":)" with smiley image doesn't work

Tags: c#

I am using visual c# to create a windows chat app, and I want all the :) words inside the chatDisplay rich text box to be replaced with a smiley image located in the resources folder.
this is my code:

```
private void add_smileys()
{
    if (chatDisplay.Text.Contains(":)"))
    {
        chatDisplay.SelectionStart = chatDisplay.Find(":)", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
        chatDisplay.SelectionLength = 2;

        String image = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Resources/smile.png");
        Image img = Image.FromFile(image);
        Clipboard.SetImage(img);
        chatDisplay.Paste();
        Console.WriteLine("All images replaced");
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors, and I don't get the "file not found" error either, and the "All images replaced" center is outputted in the console correctly. the only wrong thing is that the :) phrase in the textbox doesn't get replaced with the image. can someone help me? what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you think setting the user's clipboard and pasting it is the right way to do this?

Comment: I would use this unicode U+263A ☺

Comment: I think it's the only way to do it @Cyral ,  do you have any other ideas?

Comment: This probably is relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542850/how-can-i-insert-an-image-into-a-richtextbox

Comment: @Yogee but I want to use a real image..

Comment: @Othuna **No** user wants a program to deliberately manipulate with their clipboard.

Comment: I like Yogee's idea.  Then you can just do a simple `Replace`.  If you are insistent on the image route, I recommend avoiding the use of the clipboard as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample code for a single emoticon **:)** You may extend it for all emoticons as you need.

```
private void richTextBoxOutput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateEmoticon();
}

private void UpdateEmoticon(int startIndex = 0)
{
    const string smileKey = ":)";
    const int smileKeyLen = 2;

    DataFormats.Format myFormat = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    var index = richTextBoxOutput.Find(smileKey, startIndex, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
    if (index == -1)
        return;

    richTextBoxOutput.Select(index, smileKeyLen);

    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(Resources.smile))
    {
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(bmp);

        if (richTextBoxOutput.CanPaste(myFormat))
        {
            richTextBoxOutput.Paste(myFormat);
        }
    }

    UpdateEmoticon(startIndex + smileKeyLen);
}
```

Comment: I tried, but I get the error "the name Resources doesn't exist in the current context"

Comment: @Othuna you need to add an image on project's resources. In example code, it refers to an existing resource named "smile".

Comment: I already have an image named Smile.png in my resources @dbvega

Comment: @Othuna I think you're confused. Please, go to Properties->Resources.resx and find the image resource's name.