# Why is not an image inserted in the RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, richtextbox

I tried to insert image into `RichTextBox` by clicking the button.
I referred this post - [How can I insert an image into a RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542850/how-can-i-insert-an-image-into-a-richtextbox) and made the source code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
    f.Filter = "BMP (*.bmp)|*.bmp|JPEG (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif|GIF (*.gif)|*.gif|PNG (*.png)|*.png|All files|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif;*.gif;*.png";

    if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Get type of the file

        string typeOfFile = "";
        Stack<char> typeParse = new Stack<char>();
        int pointer = f.FileName.Length - 1
        while (pointer > 0 && f.FileName[pointer] != '.')
            typeParse.Push(f.FileName[pointer--]);
        while (typeParse.Count > 0)
            typeOfFile += typeParse.Pop();
        typeOfFile = typeOfFile.ToLower();

        // Convert Image to byte[]

        Image image = Image.FromFile(f.FileName);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        // Insert the image data in RichTextBox which is converted to hex from byte[]
        // by using BitConverter.ToString(ms.ToArray();

        StringBuilder imageRTF = new StringBuilder();
        imageRTF.Append(@"{\pict\" + typeOfFile + @"blip\picw" + image.Width + @"\pich" + image.Height);
        imageRTF.Append(@"\picwgoal" + image.Width + @"\pichgoal" + image.Height);
        imageRTF.Append(@" " + BitConverter.ToString(ms.ToArray()) + @"}");
        string rtf1 = richTextBox1.Rtf.Trim().TrimEnd('}');
        string rtf2 = imageRTF.ToString();
        richTextBox1.Rtf = rtf1 + rtf2;
    }
}
```

but when I executed and opened png file, only one line break was inserted in `RichTextBox`..
What is wrong??

Comment: My guess would be this: Your `richTextBox1.Rtf` has the following blank `Rtf` code - `{\rtf1}` - with the follwing line `string rtf1 = richTextBox1.Rtf.Trim().TrimEnd('}');` you are trimming the last `}` which results in only `{\rtf1` - closing `}` is missing now you only add your `{\pict…}` which results in `{\rtf1{\pict…}` still the closing tag for `rtf1` is missing

Comment: You could also use the ClipBoard to Copy/Paste an Image into the RTB. Maybe you'll find it easier (and you don't really need to know how RTF works).

Comment: I modified the code after seeing your comment. I deleted 3 line below the code (string rtf1, rtf2, richTextBox1.Rtf) and added `richTextBox1.Rtf = richTextBox1.Rtf + imageRTF.ToString();` but this still isn't working... did i wrong??

Comment: thank you for good information! i'll try to use the clipboard after fixing this bug

Comment: Clipboard is the most commonly used way but beware: It will always be a cludge and a rather volatile one as basically all things one would want are missing, e.g. a frame/textframe you could move around..