# how to save inserted image in rich text box C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to save an image using SaveFileDialog together with some text. the image is in a picturebox and everything is inside a rich textbox.

When I try to save the text save succesfully but the image does not.

Please Help

```
  SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog.Title = "Open file";
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "RTF files (*.rtf)|*rtf| All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".rtf";
        //om man trycker på OK
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {//skriv datan till en ny fil
            StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(File.Create(saveFileDialog.FileName));

            write.Write(richTextBox1.Text);

            write.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: How can `PictureBox` be inside `RichTextBox`? That makes no sense.

Comment: If the image is in a PictureBox, then you need a separate saving operation for that.  If the image is in the RichTextBox (no PictureBox), then you can't use the Text property.  You would have to use the Rtf property.

Comment: This is not supported.

Comment: [How can I insert an image into a RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542850/7444103) -- [Insert Plain Text and Images into RichTextBox at Runtime](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R) (many others).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Bitmap.Save() method;

```
pictureBox.Image.Save(yourPath);
```

Hope it works for you.